# AnythingSlider throws Error "base.panelSize[page] is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, anythingslider

can anybody tell me, what's wrong with my code if AnythingSlider (or rather Firebug) throws the following error when initialised?

```
base.panelSize[page] is undefined
width: base.panelSize[page][0], jquery.anythingslider.js, Line 442
```

JS-Code (inside of $(document).ready-function)):

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
  width: 800,
  height: 564,
  startPanel: 1,
  autoPlay: false,
  startStopped: true,
  animationTime: 600,
  hashTags: false,
  buildNavigation: false,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  startText: "",
  stopText: ""
});
```

i tried this with the latest version (1.5.6.2) Motties' fork of Chris Coyers' AnythingSlider (available [here](https://github.com/Mottie/AnythingSlider)).

Comment: I changed the tag java to javascript, as it doesn't seem to be related to java

Comment: This may be a problem with your HTML, could you share it please?

Comment: Hi fudgey, thanks for your reply. 
You're right; i applied the #slider to a div instead an ul (i believe this worked in a prior version, but i'm not sure, anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks for all help provided.
I was code-blind and thus applied the #slider to a div instead an ul...
(i believe this worked in a prior version, but i'm not sure, anymore)